# circularly linked list in python

Tags: python

I am stuck implementing the add function of a circularly linked list in python. I have a head pointer that should be a reference to a node, but every time I add something to the list, head is always None. Here is the code I have so far:

```
class CircleList():

    __slots__ = ('head', 'size')

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def __str__(self):
        result = "<"
        node = self.head
        count = self.size
        while count != 0:
            result = result + str(node.data)
            if count != 1:
                result = result + ", "
            node = node.next
            count -= 1
        result = result + ">"
        return result

    def add(self, element):
        head = self.head
        print(head)
        size = self.size
        if head == None:
            head = Node(element, None)
            head.next = head
        else:
            cursor = head
            while cursor.next != head:
                cursor = cursor.next
            temp = Node(element, head)
            cursor.next = temp
        size += 1


class Node():
    __slots__ = ('data','next')

    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

Here is the driver:

```
stream = open('data.txt', 'r')

circlelist = CircleList()

for name in stream
    circlelist.add(name)

print(circlelist)
```

Comment: Any reason why you implement it like this? It's not exactly pythonic, and you could easily come up with a much more elegant version extending `list`, providing meta-methods like `__getitem__` etc. and using indices. This also eliminates the need for the superfluous `Node` class. Also, I suggest sticking to the well-known interface of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only assigning the new node to your local `head` variable in your `add()` method, not to the actual `CircleList` instance member.

You might want to do something like:

```
def add(self, element):
    head = self.head
    print(head)
    size = self.size
    if head is None:
        self.head = head = Node(element, None)  # Also set the instance member.
        head.next = head
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to fix! In your add function, you assign the new head to the `head` variable -- which is restricted to the scope of the function, and will dissapear when it returns!

You have to set the value of `self.head`, the attribute of the current instance.

Edit: when you assign `head = self.head` you are making them both point to the same object. But they are separate references: whether they happen to reference the same thing or not, changing one won't change the other.